# Multi-hot encoding for a categorical variable that is space separated using tensorflow's indicator_column feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

```
import tensorflow as tf
feature_names = ['education']

d = dict(zip(feature_names, [["Bachelors","11th"]]))
print(d)
education_vocabulary_list = [
    'Bachelors', 'HS-grad', '11th', 'Masters', '9th', 'Some-college',
    'Assoc-acdm', 'Assoc-voc', '7th-8th', 'Doctorate', 'Prof-school',
    '5th-6th', '10th', '1st-4th', 'Preschool', '12th'] 
education = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('education', vocabulary_list=education_vocabulary_list)
eductation_indicator = tf.feature_column.indicator_column(education)
feature_columns = [eductation_indicator]
print(feature_columns)

input_layer = tf.feature_column.input_layer(
    features=d,
    feature_columns=feature_columns
)


with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession() as sess:
    print(input_layer)
    print(sess.run(input_layer))
```

In the above example I am getting the following output

```
[<tf.Tensor 'input_layer/concat:0' shape=(2, 16) dtype=float32>][array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],
  dtype=float32)]
```

I was expecting the output to be a dense tensor as mentioned in the link ( https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column)

Basically I want to have a multi-hot encoding for a categorical variable that is **space** separated. I would then feed that column along with other features to the DNNClassifer for model training.

How do I achieve multi-hot encoding for a categorical variable that is space separated using tensorflow's indicator_column feature ?

Comment: You have done almost everything right! You're just missing the fact that the value for the dict should be a list of list. So doing something like d = dict(zip(feature_names, [[["Bachelors","11th"]]])) should give you the result you are looking for :)

Comment: thanks .. i also found the same solution to this yesterday night :)

Comment: @kvish....how to perform the same if we have multiple features like features = {'age' : [5,6] ,'education': [['Bachelors', '11th'] , ['11th']]} .. i am getting error in this case

Comment: Is your question in reference to how to map both age and education? 
In that case, you can take a look at [make_parse_example_spec](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/make_parse_example_spec) to do that! 
Your age could be a numeric column or categorical identity column maybe?

Comment: And also, I think the 'education' feature needs to be a dense tensor. The input layer might not accept varying size list of lists. One option for you in that case may be to pad with some string like padding with zeros. That string would not be mapped to anything since it would not be in your vocabulary list so you would get the right result.

Comment: For example, if your input was features = {'age' : [5,6] ,'education': [[['Bachelors', '11th'] , ['11th', 'pad']]]}, this would be a dense tensor input to your input layer, and also pad would not be mapped to any column as it is not in vocabulary list so it would give you the right result and also enable you to pass the input properly.